Convert Sandwich toaster form 120v to 240v
I recently bought and imported what is basically a sandwich toaster from the US to Peru but I forgot about the voltage difference.
I read on a similar question the following:

Internally, the machine has matched sets of 2 things: heating elements, motor windings, etc. For 120V, they connect the two things in parallel. For 240V, they connect them in series. Sometimes there's a switch on the outside, otherwise you might have to tear into it.

I opened the device and took some pics and also drew a very crude diagramn of the connections. Can this really be turned to 240v by just making the heating elements in series? The two heating elements are clearly labeled as "120V 380W"

I added all the pictures to this albumn in case you want to see more details:
https://imgur.com/a/OPaq1se
As always, thanks in advance!

I would either return it or place a 240v to 120v transformer in the circuit.

Agreed. It's a cheap enough appliance to be considered disposable. Gift it to someone who can use it and get something that doesn't require voiding the warranty. AT BEST you would have to lose the status light, and if you have to ask I don't think I want you playing with high temperature electrical connections.

You could try this,

But you're still left with an appliance that may not have enough insulation for safe operation on 240V and the thermal switch may also no be good at 240V. be sure to use heat-proof splices.

Likely, a power transformer to convert 240 VAC to 120 VAC would cost US$35 or more, such as this example on Amazon. Peru operates at 60 Hz, the same as the U.S.A., which makes that feasible.
There are less-expensive devices that "chop" 240 VAC to reduce power, but they do not reduce peak voltage, which likely would fry the thermostat in the sandwich maker.
As others have stated, it might be more practical to donate the kitchenware to a locale with 120 VAC, 60 Hz power.


likely would fry the thermostat in the sandwich maker.* electronic controls maybe, but a lot of them use a simple bimetal strip


@ChrisH, yes, it is likely a bimetal themostat, with contact spacing designed for 120 VAC. At 240 VAC, there is increased arcing.

Admittedly my suppliers of such things are in 230V land, but the bare switches I can find are almost all rated for 240V or higher, which means the factories that export round the world are quite likely to be using parts that will work
